# how to list and run databricks notebooks using odbc driver in python

Tags: sql, odbc, databricks, pyodbc, aws-databricks

I found that databricks doesn't support stored procedures, however I have created a multiple notebooks in databricks.
If I want to list the created notebooks in databricks and run them using odbc driver in python, how do I do it?